# What can/should I do to tidy up after removing a section of baseboard?

Tags: drywall, baseboard

I'm installing a murphy bed. To get it flush with the wall, I've removed a section of baseboard. The gap where the baseboard has been removed looks pretty messy now.

[image: Wallboard removed]

I'm not *too* worried about it because, of course, the bed is going in this space and I don't expect it will be very visible most of the time. When the bed is up, it'll be completely covered; when the bed is down, I assume the mattress and bed frame and everything will obscure things. Still...

I'm just wondering what others would do in my shoes. I don't really need this to look immaculate, but is there some way to tidy things a bit, e.g. fill in the gap or cover it with something?

Comment: I would have left the baseboard on and not butted against the wall. I would think butting the murphy bed up to the wall would leave scrape markings over time on the wall itself.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a piece of thin vinyl [**base molding**](https://www.grainger.com/product/GRAINGER-APPROVED-48-x-4-PVC-Vinyl-Wall-Base-5MFJ9?cm_sp=Product_Details-_-Products_Based_on_Your_Search-_-IDPPLARECS&cm_vc=IDPPLARECS)?

[image: Base Molding]